# How can a Unity game on Android be made to show the system navigation bar?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm currently building my first game in Unity for Android and the game runs fine on my OnePlus 6T but I don't have any way of exiting the app or minimizing it to the background.

If I put the phone in sleep mode then open again for a few seconds the controls appear but then they slide down off the screen, and if I slide my finger from the bottom of the phone the controls appear for a short time again.

Is there any way in Unity to make the navigation bar show all the time?

Comment: Welcome to SO - it would be quite useful to know what you have found / tried so far, and how that did not match your expectations, could you update your question to include that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to make Unity not build the game as a fullscreen app but I also think that a game *should* be in fullscreen. As an Android user, swiping in from the side of the screen to show the navigation and status bars is exactly what I'd expect from any game and fullscreen app.

Actually, I just Googled it, apparently you can just change Screen.fullScreenMode at the beginning of your game. But I still think games should be in fullscreen mode.

Comment: If you have a source for your answer, it's useful to include a link to it